# Cant read file using PHP Filter method which has spaces

Tags: php, xml, security

I tried to read a file using the php://filter/ method..

I am able to read paths which dont have any spaces in between

```
eg: php://filter/resource=c:/windows/win.ini
```

But when i try to read a file path that has spaces, i am getting a blank response.

```
eg: php://filter/resource=C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/htdocs/xampp/phpinfo.php
```

my actual call is done through XML Entity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE gpx [<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM 'php://filter/resource=C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/htdocs/xampp/phpinfo.php'> ]>
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: @AddcitedToLearn `trim` has nothing to do with the question..

Comment: Why are you trying to use filter. Do you try to get around stream wrapper limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a couple of options:

1 - Use quotes:

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/xampp/htdocs/xampp/phpinfo.php"`

2 - Use the *shortname* for `Program Files (x86)`:

`C:/progra~2/xampp/htdocs/xampp/phpinfo.php`

Comment: Hi, updated my post.. i am doing the php request inside XML.

Comment: it would be great if you could help me pass the file as a base64.
php://filter/resource=file-in-base64

is this doable in a php filter call ?

Comment: Why don't you use `file_get_contents()` and encode the result with `base64_encode` ? I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. You my want to rephrase your question.

Comment: simply, am just trying to call a file using php://filter
i even tried 
`php://filter/resource=data://text/plain;base64,Yzovd2luZG93cy93aW4uaW5p` 
but that even returns the text , not the file